# Constant connection android sockets

Tags: java, android, python, multithreading, sockets

I've been researching stackoverflow for days now, but can't seem to find a problem like mine.

I have an **Raspberry Pi** with a **python socket server** listening for incoming messages. Also I have a **Android app** which connects to it.

My idea was to create a "simple" **music player** on the raspberry pi with the use of the **pygame** module. You can see the Android app as the controller of the music player ([Sonos](http://www.sonos.com/system?r=1) like).

*I already have a start, connecting the Android app with Raspberry pi is not the problem.
It's more how the communication between the two need to flow.*

A few "solutions" I already thought about:

1. At the moment the Android app creates a socket object and connection in a new Thread then closes the Thread (so the Thread doesn't receive or sends messages, but the socket persists). When the user clicks a button (let's say to update the music list), it opens a new Thread then uses the already created socket object to send a command, gets a response and updates the UI then terminates the Thread again. And I do this for every action that needs to happen (play, pause, stop, etc.) **With this method only the Android app has the right to ask for an action, because it's not constantly listening for server messages**
2. So what if I would create a single thread which is in a constant loop sending a message and then getting a response: how do I interact with the loop from the main UI thread (like clicking a button). I thought about a `synchronized` `List<String> MessageQueue` where the main thread pushes a command and in the connection thread's while loops it checks if there are any messages that need to be send.

I made a little schema, how I had this in mind:

Schema (single thread with while loop):
[single thread with while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAxY8.png)

Also the reason I chose sockets and not just a simple HTTP request is because later on want to update the UI so you can see real-time music playing (with the seconds updating and stuff like almost every musicplayer has, and who knows what more.

If you guys have any idea's, or know of any topics, example applications on how to create this then please share! If some things are not clear or are a little vague, feel free to ask/comment because I just started with asking on forums.

Example applications that use persistent socket connections with real-time communication are also welcome!

*side question: would JSON be a good way to communicate between the 2 applications?*

*like this:*

```
{
   currentsong: "song1.mp3"
   position: "1.30" // The current position the music is playing on the server
   songlist: ["song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song4.mp3"]
   ...
}
```